# Jquery ajax response data inserted in the same div id instead of based on checkbox id's

Tags: jquery, ajax, iteration, each, checkbox

I have this JQuery code:

```
jQuery("#form").click(function() {

$("input[name='copyno']:checked").each(function() {

    checkboxData = "copyno="+$(this).val();

id=$(this).val();

   jQuery.ajax({
      url: "renewall.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: checkboxData,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {

    $("#" +id).html(data);             

    }
});
});
});
```

What I'am trying to do is to put the response data into specific divs based on checkboxes values, in this case the id, but the response data only shows in the same div id (
id=$(this).val();) instead of to be shown there where it has the same id value.

Som Kind og iteration problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy of your code you showed me in the screencast:

```
$("input[name='copyno']:checked").each(function() {
    checkboxData = "copyno="+$(this).val();
    ids = $(this).val();

    jQuery.ajax({

       url: "renewall.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: checkboxData,
       cache: false,
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(data) {

          var divs = $(data).filter(function() { 
                                       return $(this).is('#stil2'); //<-- add semicolon
          });

          divs.each(function() {
             $("#" + ids).html(this);
          });
       }
    });
});
```

Anyway the important part is to properly declare your `id` variable within your `click` function like:

```
$("input[name='copyno']:checked").each(function() {
    checkboxData = "copyno="+$(this).val();
    var ids = $(this).val();

    //rest of your code...

});
```

So do note that **var** instantiator right before the **divs**. This should fix your problem. If you don't do this, the variable is set for the first call, but is overwritten by the second. So eventually when both calls finish, they will just have the same **ids** value which is your second div.

Comment: Thx man, you saved me a lot, i thought that I had tried that but it seems that it was with a diffrent success code...

Comment: When I have a long list of copyno's it becomes too slow before the blocks show up, it may be the dom manipulation html(), any suguestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make `id` a global variable at the start of the script, you will then be able to use it in the ajax function:

```js
var id=null;

/*... your code... */
```